# remove() not working in jquery, turn no method

Tags: jquery

```
var deleteTarget = $('ul li .active');
deleteTarget.remove();
```

Not sure what's wrong, the console says it `has no method`, or shall I still use `$(deleteTarget)` ?

Comment: A wild guess: try `ul li .active`

Comment: try deleteTarget.empty();

Comment: @HamZa, probably true, but not answering the question.

Comment: @Kaitlyn Sacco have you added more than one jquery.js

Answer (score 2):

`$` is obviously not jQuery in your case.

You can check if it is with:

```
console.log($().jquery); // if undefined, it's not jQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery string is almost certainly wrong.

`#` queries for ID

You probably wanted to do:

```
var deleteTarget = $('ul li .active');
```

Comment: Perhaps, but that wouldn't account for the symptom given: *"the console says it has no method"*

Comment: Agree, will be probably combination of both

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one ???

```
$("ul li").remove(".active");
```

id try mixin up the codes from this site [Here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: I want to remove the li, not the class